# How compile function written in python to JavaScript (emscripten)?

Tags: javascript, python, cython, emscripten

I have a simple function written in python which I want to port to javascript.

I have compiled python 2.7 into a .so library, so thats not the issue.

The problem I'm having is that after I compile my program with cython, the function names get all scrambled up, which means I don't know how to preserve the functions when i run emcc.

Does anybody have any experience compiling python programs to js with emscripten?

Any information would be appreciated.

Note: I want to preserve the exact functionality to that of python, I don't want something that translates a python program into javascript.

Comment: There are more direct ways of turning Python into JavaScript, which may be more appropriate for your situation.  The projects listed in the Python section here: http://altjs.org/#ports and here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#python may all be viable options for you.

Comment: You may also find this project interesting: https://github.com/replit/jsrepl. It's a multi-language scripting engine in javascript that you can run in a browser. Supports Python (which I think was ported to it using emscripten). So instead of compiling Python to js you can just send Python to the browser.

Comment: Given the SO question I found and posted below, I think @slebetman is right, that doing the sort of thing that jsrepl does to run arbitrary Python code against its emscripten-compiled CPython interpreter is going to be your best bet if you want to preserve the original Python code.  https://github.com/replit/empythoned is their Python-specific example.

Comment: You can also run Python scripts in JavaScript using Skulpt: http://www.skulpt.org/

Answer (score 6):

This other question, with an accepted answer, complains about the same issue: Cython mangling function names and making it difficult to access from C++: [Embed python function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810815/embed-python-function-in-c)

The accepted answer states that Cython isn't meant for this sort of thing at all, suggesting you can't do what you want in this fashion:

> You're not going to be able to get the interoperation you want that way. If you open and inspect hello.c you won't find "static int say_hello" anywhere in there. Cython is designed for letting Python use C libraries, not letting C libraries use python.

The not-accepted next answer suggest that specifying `public` will not mangle the function name, although he also mentions linking problems.

```
# (in the generated C file hello.c)
__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(...) say_hello(...);
```

Worth a shot, but please consider the other options in the comments if it fails.

Comment: Right, but my function names after going through cython get scrambled up, to "my_func" is called "<bunch of weird stuff>_my_func" now.